# Reasons to ask to waive a GRE test score

Tags: masters, computer-science, gre

I am interested in pursuing a master's in computer science at the university where I completed my undergrad (also in computer science). I haven't taken the GRE which is required for entry. Some graduate programs at my university waive the GRE requirement if you're a graduate from the university, I asked the program director and he said it could be waived with a good undergrad record and a letter of justification or a recommendation from other faculty. I have a 3.5 undergrad GPA which is more than enough to get into the program.

What kinds of justification would be a "good" justification in the case of this? I haven't taken it because I'm nervous and since I started a new job right after graduation I haven't had time to study for it. However, by the time the fall semester starts I would be more comfortable in my job and will have more time to devote to the program.

I am very serious about this program and fear if I don't get admission this upcoming semester then the professors (and department chair) who were my references would either forget about me or not write me another recommendation. Not to mention the year that would pass and all the knowledge I would lose during that time.

Should I take the GRE under prepared, or wait until next spring and hope that I can find equally good references?

Comment: We cannot know the answer to this as it applies to your department.  Talk to the program director again and ask for clarification as to what kind of justification would be acceptable for a waiver. Ask him what should be addressed in a recommendation.  You might also be able to talk to other faculty who are on the graduate admission committee. Then talk to one or more faculty members who know you well and ask if they could write you a recommendation on that basis.

Comment: Tell the director that you've just started a new job and you're focusing on making a good impression there and don't want to take time out for the GRE. I haven't sat on master's admissions committees, but it sounds like a good rationalization to me, especially coupled with the fact that you've just graduated there and they have your grades and performance fresh in mind. The worst they can do is say no. It sounds like you've got one or more professors who could write you a recommendation as a good student, which is all the GRE is really trying to assess.

Comment: I am concerned that citing the new job might suggest that you won't have the time to devote to grad studies while working.  But by all means, talk to the program director. // In the worst case, you could enroll as a non-matriculated student in the fall.

Comment: My job was mostly the reason- I was done with school for the moment and trying to work as hard as possible to make a good impression. By the time the fall semester starts I'd have about 6 months of experience and my job would know I was back at school so they would understand if I cut back a little bit. That being said I'm more serious about my education than I am the job. I've been accepted to the cyber security master's program, and have been thinking of accepting that and trying to transfer to the computer science program once I have a few semesters since many of the classes are the same.